# Material ui - unable to set height of popover menu opened from a Select Validator

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, web-applications, material-ui

I am trying to alter the height of a popover that appears from a select validator form in Material UI.  I have tried adding the below CSS to the overall class (and a great many other approaches):

```
'& .MuiPopover-paper': {
  height: '330px',
},
```

However, neither this nor anything else I've tried seems to be working.  I can alter the height property of the element .MuiPopover-paper if I inspect it in the browser console.  Plus, changing it there works exactly as expected and gives me the desired result.  I know I somehow am not accessing the element properly in the style sheet/code, but none of the approaches I have tried works.

This is the JS/JSX code:

```
<SelectValidator
    id="color" 
    inputRef={this.formRefs.color}
    value={color}
    onChange={handleChangeByEvent}
    variant="outlined"
    name='color'
    className={classes.boder}
    validators={['required']}
    errorMessages={["Please select your vehicle's color"]}
>
        <MenuItem value="" className={classes.option}>
            <em>None</em>
        </MenuItem>
        {
            vehicleColors.map(color => {
                return <MenuItem key={color.id} value={color} className={classes.option}>       
                {color.name}</MenuItem>
            })
         }
</SelectValidator>
```

Here is the corresponding CSS:

```
border: {
    width: '100%',
    margin: '7px 0',
    borderRadius: '1px',
    color: '#333',
    fontSize: '14px',
    '& .MuiSelect-iconOutlined': {
        top: 'auto',
        fontSize: '24px',
        color: '#fff',
        marginRight: '10px',
        backgroundImage: `url(${downImg})`,
    },
    '& .MuiSelect-select': {
        height: '48px',
        width: '100%',
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        border: 'solid 1px #6e6e6e',
        padding: '0 14px',
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
        fontFamily: 'FordAntenna-Regular',
        color: '#333',
        fontSize: '14px',
        borderRadius: '3px',
    },
},
```

Answer (score 3):

Figured this out after some tinkering.  The popover is not a child of the root element or any children of the root.  It is created and rendered when the popover is accessed at runtime, using built-in Material-ui classes.

Therefore, the settings for the built-in classes must be overriden.

This can be accomplished by creating a styleOverrides.css file with the code below (must be a .css, adding this code in your styles.js will not work). Then import the .css in the component where the popover you want to alter is generated.

```
.MuiMenu-paper.MuiPopover-paper {
    max-height: 300px //or whatever attribute you want to alter
}
```

Comment: I need !important on this rule as well for it to work. Is there really no way to override this more cleanly in the theme component style overrides?